# Determine (with justification) whether the series converges or diverges. (Integral test)

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider:
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} (1/{((k+1)ln(k+1)))}$$

This is what I have as an answer so far:

We consider $f(x) = 1/((x+1)ln(x+1))$. We note f is continous, positive, and decreasing from $[1,∞)$. Now we calculate $$
\int_1^{∞} 1/((x+1)ln(x+1))\, dx
$$ is equal to

$$\lim _{t\to ∞}  
\int_1^{t} 1/((x+1)ln(x+1)\, dx
$$

Now by sepearting the the fraction I have

$$\lim _{t\to ∞}  
\int_1^{t} 1/(x+1)*1/(ln(x+1))\, dx
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{x\ln x} dx = \ln(\ln x)$

Comment: Could I do a u-sub, so u = x+1, du = 1. So now I would have $$\lim _{t\to ∞}  
\int_1^{t} 1/(ulnu)\, du
$$ Therefore that would be equal to ln(lnu) = ln(ln(x+1)) correct?

Comment: Yes, and your integral is $\displaystyle \int_{2}^\infty$

Comment: Ok great, so then my answer would be infinity, since ln(ln(u)) goes towards infinity, and subracting ln(ln(2)) wont make a difference to infinity.

Comment: And since we know the integral diverges, we then know that the series diverges.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: YES! Thank you I really didn't know if I was taking the integral correctly, since I was given a series.